# Why does node report old version despite having installed NVM and latest LTS, when asking as root through sudo?

Tags: unix, node.js, nvm

Before installing NVM and latest LTS Node for `foo` user:

```
foo@ubuntu: which node
/usr/bin/node
foo@ubuntu: node --version
v12.22.1
```

After having installed NVM and latest LTS Node:

```
foo@ubuntu: which node
/home/foo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node
foo@ubuntu: node --version
v14.16.1
```

Then why does node still report old version when asking as **root** through sudo?

```
root@ubuntu: sudo -u foo which node
/usr/bin/node
root@ubuntu: sudo -u foo node --version
v12.22.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because when you are root and you are sudoing to foo it's not sourcing foo's PATH to the newer version.

If you want to test and fix this as

root

```
echo $PATH
```

as foo

```
echo $PATH
```

to fix in root's .bashrc append /home/foo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node